# Bold certain part of Ipywidgets Button text

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipywidgets

I am creating a button in Jupyter Notebook using ipywidgets with the following code:

```
from IPython.display import Javascript, display
from ipywidgets import widgets
from ipywidgets import Layout,interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual, IntSlider, HBox, Label
def run_all(ev):
    display(Javascript('IPython.notebook.execute_cell_range(IPython.notebook.get_selected_index()+1, IPython.notebook.get_selected_index()+2)'))

button = widgets.Button(description="This is a blue colored earth",layout=Layout(width='70%', height='40px'),
                        style=dict(text_color='#FFFFFF'))
button.style.button_color = '#ff9838'

button.on_click(run_all)
display(button)
```

Now this is generating the following output:
[image]

Now I want to bold certain part of the text in the button.. Let's say "blue colored earth"
Can you please help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-make-certain-words-of-button-description-bold/9148):

It looks like it will be possible to use HTML tags in the description when version 8 is out.

Because the description accepts unicode, for now the workaround is to use a site like this [Unicode Text Converter](http://slothsoft.net/UnicodeMapper/?lang=en-us) to get the bold version of the text and then replace the corresponding part of description with that bold version.

Applying to version extracted from your code with `blue colored earth` in bold:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import Layout
button = widgets.Button(description="This is a   ",layout=Layout(width='70%', height='40px'),
                        style=dict(text_color='#FFFFFF'))
button
```

Comment: Hey @Wayne, thanks. This solution works in my Jupyter. Just to confirm, does it works in older Jupyter Notebooks and Python as well?

Comment: It works in the classic notebook interface that is currently available. (A newer version of the classic notebook is in the works that will have more of the modern underlying machinery that JupyterLab has, and so it should be stable as it works in JupyterLab at present, too.) Also works in Voila. I don't know what you mean by it working in Python? The full name is 'ipywidgets: Interactive HTML Widgets' and pure Python has no graphical user interface to be interactive or display HTML. (Traditionally, at least. Pyscript is a different beast.)

Comment: Oh... I wasn't aware of it. I thought ipywidgets was python's internal package/module.

Comment: I should have also said [the documentation page](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#) has the title 'Jupyter Widgets', as does [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets). [The ipywidgets page](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets#ipywidgets-interactive-html-widgets) also says, "ipywidgets, also known as jupyter-widgets or simply widgets, are interactive HTML widgets for Jupyter notebooks and the IPython kernel."  The components of the Python standard library are listed at https://docs.python.org/3/library/.